# How to change decimal seprator from "." to "," in EditText Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:digits="0123456789,"
    android:gravity="center"/>
```

After Defining digits it allow me to use "," but only problem I am facing that, I can enter "," multiple time. I want to restrict user so that he can input only one Decimal separator that is comma "," in my case.

Comment: Does your device's chosen locale use a `,` or a `.` for a decimal separator?

Comment: No when I change language of phone to dutch, after that it behaving same taking "." as a decimal separator, not ","

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
boolean hasComma = false;     
InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
                                   Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {

            if (hasComma && (source.equals(".") || source.equals(",")))
            {
                return "";
            }
            return source;

        }
    };

// set input filter for edit text

editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{filter});

editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

         }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                if(!hasComma && s.toString().contains("."))
                {
                    s= replaceComma(s.toString());
                    editText.setText(s);
                    editText.setSelection(start + 1);
                    hasComma =true;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if (s.toString().contains(",") || s.toString().contains("."))
                {
                    hasComma =true;
                }
                else {

                    hasComma = false;

                }
            }
        });

//use this method to replace "." to ","
    private CharSequence replaceComma(String s) {
        return s.replace('.',',');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure it depends on the locale your device is on.